# Next.js/Mongodb Assignment Status for Individual Student in a LMS

Tags: database, mongodb, database-design, next.js

I am building a MERN (with Next.js) stack Learning Management System. Currently, I have built the front-end for the Assignments that lists the assignments for that course. For example, if I am logged in, I will see all my assignments for PHIL 204 course if I go to `test.com/courses/PHIL204/Assignments`. Now, in this table, there is a column that says "Status" which tells if the assignment has been started, submitted, or graded (only 3 values). My question is, how do I store/calculate this value? I have Students and Assignments as two collections (out of many) in my DB. My DB is still in dev, so I can easily follow your suggestions. I don't suppose the Assignments col should have a "status" field because that would show the same for all students that have that assignment. If you need any code from me, I can provide that. I am seeking help mostly for the logic of what/how to store if a student has started, submitted, or graded(by the prof) that assignment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, GitHub Copilot suggested me that in the Students schema I have something like this:

```
const studentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    studentFirstName : {type : String, required: true},
    studentLastName : {type : String, required: true},
    studentEmail : {type : String, required: true},
    studentClass : {type : String},
    studentAssignments : [{
        assignmentId : {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Assignments'},
        assignmentGrade : {type : String, enum : ["A","A-","B+","B","B-","C+","C","C-","D+","D","D-","F"]},
        assignmentStatus : {type : String, enum : ["Not Started", "Started", "Submitted", "Returned"]},
        assignmentRemarks : {type : String},
        assignmentCompeletedDate : {type : Date},
    }],
    studentTestQuizzes : [{
        testQuizId : {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'TestQuizzes'},
        testQuizGrade : {type : String, enum : ["A","A-","B+","B","B-","C+","C","C-","D+","D","D-","F"]},
        testQuizStatus : {type : String, enum : ["Not Started", "Submitted", "Returned"]},
        testQuizRemarks : {type : String},
        testQuizCompletedDate : {type : Date},
    }],
    studentAnnouncements : [{
        announcementId : {type : Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Announcements'},
        announcementStatus : {type : String, enum : ["Read", "Not Read"]},
    }],
    // we need a courseId to link the student to a course

}, { collection: 'Students' });
```

This should work. I will update this thread, if it does not work or if I need to do some more work.